# Doctrine2 cannot insert into associated table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, controller

I try to insert into association table between 2 tables,
I have this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Acme\HomeBundle\Entity\AuthUsergroup::setLogin() must be an instance
>   of Acme\HomeBundle\Entity\AuthUser, string given, called in
>   /var/www/html/prj/src/Acme/HomeBundle/Controller/UserController.php
>   on line 73 and defined

and that line 73 is : $aug->setLogin($my_id);
and this function comes from :

```
/**
 * Set login
 *
 * @param \Acme\HomeBundle\Entity\AuthUser $login
 *
 * @return AuthUsergroup
 */
public function setLogin(\Acme\HomeBundle\Entity\AuthUser $login = null)
{
    $this->login = $login;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can you dump `$my_id`please ? The problem seems to be that it is a string, instead of a AuthUser object.

Comment: that give me : string(6) "Fred", so how can i change that to an object ?

Comment: You should post your AuthUser entity code, but something like this I guess : `$newAuth = new AuthUser(); $newAuth->setName($my_id);`. But I must advise you to be coherent in your methods and variable names : $my_id should be an id, that's to say an integer, with which you could find Objects, whatever they may be. Here your naming is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory : the `setLogin()` methods expects a AuthUser object, and you are giving it a string. You have to pass to do something like this :

```
$newAuth = new AuthUser();
// assuming the AuthUser class has a setName() method
$newAuth->setName($my_id);
// You pass a AuthUser object -> no more exception thrown
$aug->setLogin($newAuth);
```

Hope this helps.